# C# return (dynamic or anonymous?) object with return values from other methods as properties

Tags: c#, dynamic, return, anonymous-objects

I would like to return an object, which stores the return values from other class methods as properties on the return object. The problem is that I do not know which is the best way to do this in C#. Currently I am using a sort of JavaScript-ish approach. Because I do not know the return type, I use the dynamic keyword.

```
class Test {

    public static dynamic MyExportingMethod() {
        return new {
            myString = MyStringMethod(),
            myInt = MyIntMethod()
        };
    }

    public static string MyStringMethod() {
        return "Hello";
    }

    public static int MyIntMethod() {
        return 55;
    }

   }
```

And then being able to access them like so,

```
var myReturnObjWithProps = Test.MyExportingMethod();
myReturnObjWithProps.myString; // should be "Hello"
```

So my questions are, should I use the dynamic return type? Am I not just returning an anonymous object?

Comment: How about creating a class that has the properties `MyString` and `MyInt`, and returning that class instead?

Comment: You cannot return an anonymous type, I would advise you not to use dynamic when you don't know when you should use it. Use tuples or create a data class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> should I use the dynamic return type?

Yes - a method that returns `dynamic` effectively returns an `object`, so you have to use `dynamic` in order to access it's properties at runtime without reflection.

> Am I not just returning an anonymous object?

You are, but the declared type of the method is effectively `object` so its properties cannot be referenced at compile-time.

Bottom line - you should avoid returning anonymous types from methods if at all possible. Use a defined type, or keep the creation and usage of the anonymous type in one method so you can use `var` and let the compiler infer the type.

Comment: Thank you for your answer D Stanley! Lets say I do not want to create a return class type, as suggested by Palle Due. I want to keep returning an anonymous object - does anonymous objects always require dynamic keyword? And could you elaborate what you meant by its properties cannot be referenced at compile time.

Comment: The structure of the anonymous type is only known within the method that creates it. If you insist on returning an anonymous type then your only options are to use either reflection or dynamic (which uses reflection behind-the-scenes) to get the property values at run-time.

Answer (score 2):

Make a class for the return type. You want something strongly typed, both for performance and for clarity.

```cs
class Foo
{
    string MyString { get; set}
    int MyInt { get; set}
}

class Test 
{

    public static Foo MyExportingMethod() 
    {
        return new Foo
        {
            MyString = MyStringMethod(),
            MyInt = MyIntMethod()
        };
    }

    public static string MyStringMethod() 
    {
        return "Hello";
    }

    public static int MyIntMethod() 
    {
        return 55;
    }
}
```

You should use `dynamic` sparingly. This way anyone can see what your method is returning. If you return dynamic the caller has no way of knowing what to look for in the dynamic without looking at the source for your method. That way the abstraction goes away and well-structured programming is all about abstraction.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Palle Due! I was wondering, what you meant by "anyone can see what your method is returning"? Thanks in advance from a C# beginner.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to creating a new class simply for a method return would be [`ValueTuple`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.valuetuple?view=netcore-3.1):

```
public static (string myString, int myInt) MyExportingMethod()
{
    return (MyStringMethod(), MyIntMethod());
}

var (myString, myInt) = Test.MyExportingMethod();
myString; // == "Hello"
```